# Node.js: Sharing object data between multiple files

Tags: javascript

I am creating an Electron application and would like to create one Config type object that is shared throughout the application. My initial idea was to use a singleton, but that only worked when I was creating new instances of an object within the same file where the class was created.

What I am trying to achieve is having one Config object whose data is shared between multiple `require()` statements in different files. I hope the example below clears things up. In other words, once `file1.js` starts modifying variables within the config object, I want `file2.js` to see those changes. The two files should then be able to almost 'share' the data in the object.

The only idea I can think of is to use global variables and then just make all the class functions static. So instead of `this.variable = '...';` I would use `global.variable = '...';`. That way even if multiple objects of the Config class were created, they would still share the variable values. Would this be the better route to take?

Local Files:

```
-- ../lib/config.js --

class Config {
    constructor(){
        if(!Config.instance){
            console.log('creating instance');
            this.variable = '...';
            Config.instance = this;
        }

        console.log('returning instance');
        return Config.instance;
    }

    getValue() { return this.variable }
   
    setValue(val) { this.variable = val }
}

const configHandler = new Config();
module.exports = configHandler;
```

```
--file1.js--

const config = require('../lib/config');
```

```
--file2.js--

const config = require('../lib/config');
```

Current console output

```
creating instance
returning instance
creating instance
returning instance
```

Expected console output

```
creating instance
returning instance
returning instance
```

Comment: Rather than implement it from scratch yourself, why not use a package for that, like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-store)?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by using global variables.

```
class Config {
    constructor(){
        this.variable = '...';
    }

    getValue() { return this.variable }
   
    setValue(val) { this.variable = val }
}

if (!global.configHandler) {
    global.configHandler = new Config();
    module.exports = configHandler;
} else {
    module.exports = global.configHandler;
}
```

Basically, if the config object already exists in the global scope I export the object. If not, I create the new config object, set it to a global variable, and then finally I export the variable.